# Cakephp 3 How to Save data of hasMany and belogsToMany association

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0

I have the following model :

Participants
Options
Inscriptions (Subscriptions)

Associations are as following :

Inscriptions hasMany Participants

```
$this->hasMany('Participants', [
            'foreignKey' => 'inscription_id'
        ]);
```

Participants belongsToMany Options

```
$this->belongsToMany('Options', [
            'joinTable' => 'options_participants',
        ]);
```

Options belongsToMany Participants

```
$this->belongsToMany('Participants', [
            'joinTable' => 'options_participants',
        ]);
```

I would like to save one Inscription

```
 $_datas = $this->request->data;
    $inscription = $this->Inscriptions->patchEntity($inscription, $_datas, ['associated' => ['Participants.Options']]);
$inscription->save();
```

This is my form for each Participant of the Inscription (into a foreach loop).

```
 <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.id');
    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.civilite', ['type' => 'select', 'data-update' => 'civiliteUpdate', 'label' => 'Civilité*', 'empty' => '(choisissez)', 'options' => $_civilite, 'value' => $_participant->civilite]);
    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.nom', ['class' => 'edit-nom', 'data-update' => 'nomUpdate', 'field' => 'nom', 'label' => 'Nom*', 'value' => $_participant->nom]);
    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.prenom', ['class' => 'edit-prenom', 'data-update' => 'prenomUpdate', 'field' => 'prenom', 'label' => 'Prénom*', 'value' => $_participant->prenom]);
    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.formule_id', ['type' => 'select', 'data-update' => 'formuleNomUpdate', 'field' => 'formule', 'data-url' => $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Inscriptions', 'action' => 'ajaxReturnFormulePrice']), 'label' => 'Formule*', 'empty' => '(Choisissez)', 'options' => $formules, 'value' => $_participant->formule_id]);
    echo $this->Form->label('participants.' . $i . '.dateDeNaissance', 'Date de naissance');

    echo $this->Form->day('participants.' . $i . '.dateDeNaissance', ['label' => '', 'value' => $_participant->dateDeNaissance->day]);
    echo $this->Form->month('participants.' . $i . '.dateDeNaissance', ['label' => '', 'value' => $_participant->dateDeNaissance->month]);
    echo $this->Form->year('participants.' . $i . '.dateDeNaissance', ['label' => '', 'value' => $_participant->dateDeNaissance->year, 'minYear' => 1931, 'maxYear' => date('Y')]);

    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.email', ['value' => $_participant->email, 'data-update' => 'emailUpdate']);
    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.telephone', ['value' => $_participant->telephone]);
    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.codePostal', ['value' => $_participant->codePostal]);
    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.adresse', ['value' => $_participant->adresse]);
    echo $this->Form->input('participants.' . $i . '.ville', ['value' => $_participant->ville]);?>
```

The question is how to put in this form an input field to specify that a Participant belongsToMany Options.

Thank you for your help.